# Redirecting Joomla Links to New ExpressionEngine Links Fails

Tags: redirects, redirection

I'm running into an issue where 301 redirects on site I switched from Joomla to EE are not working. The link style on the old version of the site is:

http://example.com/index.php?option=com_user&view=reset&Itemid=14

For the redirect, I'm using this line in the .htaccess:

`Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_user&view=reset&Itemid=14 /contact`

Since index.php is valid with EE, my assumption is the issue revolves around the query string since a more basic redirect works as indended:

`Redirect 301 /about /`

routes traffic from the about page to the home page.

How can I redirect these links to the new ExpressionEngine-powered pages or, if the issue is more generic, links containing "index.php?"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **%{QUERY_STRING}**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_user&view=reset&Itemid=14$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /contact? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That was 99.99998% there! It should be `/contact? [L,R=301]` otherwise the `option=...` bit is appended to the redirected URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Max! Not quite wrapping my head around the ? being necessary... my understanding is that means what directly proceeds it can be optional but in this case, it seems to impact what comes after?